# How to locate non-circular limit cycles?

Tags: dynamical-systems

Recently I've encountered limit cycles in dynamical systems
which are basically a cyclic trajectory.
From what I understand, there are different types of limit cycles for example stable and unstable limit cycle (for an $\epsilon$ environment we’ll be pulled into the cycle or pushed out of the cycle environment).
One of the ways to locate a limit cycle is to present the dynamic 
system with polar coordinates and try to find the right values 
such that $r'$ will be $0$, which will point out a limit cycle with
unchanging radius (a circle).

But I’ve seen that there are limit cycles which are not circular, for instance in the attached picture, we can see there is a limit cycle with changing radius ($r'$ is probably a function of $\theta$ as well).

[image: Non circular limit cycle]

My question is: **How can we locate the limit cycle in these situations?**

Comment: What software did you use for the phase portrait? Would you mind to share the code? Always looking for good plots :D. As Soon As I have access to a PC I will write you an answer.

Comment: well i got that picture from wikipedia
but you can do that with couple of lines in Maple
its great software for mathamatics and for differential equations and dynamic systems in particular.
i think i can find some code for plots like these
(its really friendly-usable software for ploting things out you should try it out).
  
oh and thanks in advance (:

Comment: Maple and Matlab plots are not very good looking. I always need to take the data and use tikz to make them pretty :D.

Comment: Also don't forget that if your system comes as a member of some parameterized family, you should look for a Hopf bifurcation — this is one of the simplest bifurcations that give rise to limit cycles. Hopf bifurcation points is also a good starting point for collocation methods: you know where approximately solution is, that's the benefit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the possible exception of some carefully crafted examples, you have to resort to numerical methods:

- The trajectory of stable limit cycles can be found by integrating the differential equations. If the solution exhibits a periodic behaviour (after a while), you have a limit cycle. If an optical assessment of periodicity is not sufficient or possible, you can compute the [Lyapunov exponents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_exponents) (if the largest one is zero and the next is negative, you have a limit cycle) or apply [this periodicity test of mine](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.4934968).
- To locate an unstable limit cycle, you can try integrating backwards in time.
  If this doesn’t work, e.g., because the backwards integration is not a well-behaving problem, you have to resort to [collocation methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation_method).
  Briefly, you set up a generic limit cycle composed of piecewise polynomials and try to choose the parameters such that the trajectory solves your differential equation at certain, fine-sampled points.
  For further reading, consider starting [here](https://scholar.google.de/scholar?cluster=8017950729804620067).

Comment: how havent i thought about integrating.... Thanks!! seems like it should do the work!